# Deployed Mvc app won't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I'm having some problems publishing an asp.net mvc3 application. When deployed, the application fails with "The controller for path '/Dashboard/Alarmes' was not found or does not implement IController" where Alarmes is an action at DashboardController. Not sure if it has something to do with it, but Alarmes return an Json result.

Another thing I noticed is that some assemblies, that are referenced by another project in the same solution, are not deployed (only if I reference them in the mvc project itself).

Any tips on these?

**Update:**

The routes registration:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allpng}", new { allpng = @".*\.png(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{directory}/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {
                controller = "Dashboard",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
        }
```

the action:

```
public ActionResult Alarmes() {
    var alarmesPorPonto = new Dictionary<string, List<Ponto>>();
    var alarmes = _repositorioDeAlarmes.Pesquise(ObtenhaInicio(), DateTime.Today);

    foreach (var alarme in alarmes) {
        var tipo = alarme.Tipo;
        var ponto = alarme.Ponto;

        if (!alarmesPorPonto.ContainsKey(tipo.Nome)) {
            alarmesPorPonto.Add(tipo.Nome, new List<Ponto>());
        }

        if (!alarmesPorPonto[tipo.Nome].Contains(ponto)) {
            alarmesPorPonto[tipo.Nome].Add(ponto);
        }
    }

    return Json(alarmesPorPonto.Select(a => new { Tipo = a.Key, a.Value.Count }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Another missing info: I'm deploying this application to a virtual directory.

**Update 2**

the full controller class:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller {
        private readonly IRepositorioDeAlarmes _repositorioDeAlarmes;
        private readonly bool _enableMap;      

        public DashboardController(IRepositorioDeAlarmes repositorioDeAlarmes) {
            _repositorioDeAlarmes = repositorioDeAlarmes;
            _enableMap = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableMap"]);            
        }

        public ActionResult Index() {
            ViewBag.EnableMap = _enableMap;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Alarmes() {
            var alarmesPorPonto = new Dictionary<string, List<Ponto>>();
            var alarmes = _repositorioDeAlarmes.Pesquise(ObtenhaInicio(), DateTime.Today);

            foreach (var alarme in alarmes) {
                var tipo = alarme.Tipo;
                var ponto = alarme.Ponto;

                if (!alarmesPorPonto.ContainsKey(tipo.Nome)) {
                    alarmesPorPonto.Add(tipo.Nome, new List<Ponto>());
                }

                if (!alarmesPorPonto[tipo.Nome].Contains(ponto)) {
                    alarmesPorPonto[tipo.Nome].Add(ponto);
                }
            }

            return Json(alarmesPorPonto.Select(a => new { Tipo = a.Key, a.Value.Count }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your routing config code and DashboardController code please?

Comment: Could you post your controller class definition as well? Is the assembly containing this controller present in the `bin` folder of your deployed website?

Comment: @Darin yes it is. The page itself can be accessed, but the call to the action Alarmes fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have hardcoded the url in your javascript when invoking the action instead of using an url helper.

So you wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/Alarmes', function(result) {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Alarmes", "Dashboard")', function(result) {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

which would have generated the correct url in the case when your application is hosted in a virtual directory which would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('/MyAppName/Dashboard/Alarmes', function(result) {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Fernando, sometimes the symptoms are enough to provide a diagnosis. When you said that the `Index` action was working fine but not the `Alarmes` action that you were invoking through AJAX and that this happens only when you deploy your application in a virtual directory it was clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to clean the ASP.Net temporary files and restart the web server?
[{windows-path}\Microsoft.NET\Framework{framework-version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files]